# Layout bug on question lists

Tags: bug, design, homepage

On the "home page" which lists currently active questions, the question titles are not aligned horizontally.  (At least on SO and Meta.SO.  I haven't checked other SE sites.)

When there's exactly one answer, the status on the left says "answer," which is slightly shorter than "answers" (plural) shown in all other cases.  That difference in length causes the adjacent column's horizontal position to shift accordingly.

Admittedly, this imperfect alignment is very minor, but it's annoying when trying to scan down the currently active questions.

Repro'ed on current Chrome stable, on a couple machines, with various window sizes and display densities.

**Update**:  Yes, browser zoom at 100%.  Screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Screenshot and diagrams please.

Comment: No repro on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 75.0

Comment: I've got Chrome something-or-other on Windows 7, and I don't see this. But I'm not sure if it's because I'm just misunderstanding what UI bug you're referring to.

Comment: @CodyGray I think what's implied is something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPrLL.png), answers being a longer string than answer causes the div to widen offsetting the question title... that said... no repro, I had to edit the page for this

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought Adrian was referring to, @Nick. I can't repro that at all. Even by editing the HTML and changing "answers" to "answer", the question titles still line up vertically.

Comment: Oh, no I had to force the width of the div to be larger, nothing else did it

Comment: Are you using 100% default zoom?

Comment: @SamuelLiew:  Sorry about the delay.  Screenshot added.  Yes, browser zoom is at 100%.

Comment: As of today, it looks like this has been fixed by making better use of the space on the left.  Thanks!!!